# Firebeetle ESP8266 and micropython

Tags: esp8266, micropython, esp8266wifi

I have gotten stuck while flashing micropython firmware into the board.

Erasing flash finished with success as you can see below:

**esptool.py --chip esp8266 --port /dev/ttyUSB0 erase_flash**

```
esptool.py v3.2
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 8c:aa:b5:69:d9:e3
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Erasing flash (this may take a while)...
Chip erase completed successfully in 11.7s
```

but flashing the firmware is not

**esptool.py --chip esp8266 --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash --flash_mode dio --flash_size=detect --compress 0x00000 firmware/esp8266-1m-20220117-v1.18.bin**

```
esptool.py v3.2
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 8c:aa:b5:69:d9:e3
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Flash will be erased from 0x00000000 to 0x00090fff...
Flash params set to 0x0240
Compressed 591524 bytes to 391472...
Writing at 0x00000000... (4 %)
A fatal error occurred: Failed to write compressed data to flash after seq 0 (result was C100: Unknown result)
```

I tried to change the baud rate, but it didn't help.
Any suggestions or hints? Maybe I bricked the board?

Comment: Have you tried it without `--compress`? They don't suggest that in the [micropython docs](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/intro.html).

Comment: Yes, I did - no success.

Comment: The issue was with the CP210x USB to UART Bridge Virtual COM Port (VCP) drivers on my OS - Ubuntu 20. 
On Windows 10, I didn't see any problems and I continued working on that OS.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!